# Spring web security 4 not working on the existing spring project with java based config

Tags: spring, spring-security

I developing spring 4 web project and angularjs app on front-end. I use java based spring security configuration. Now I try implement the Spring web security 4 for the user authorization. I created `SecurityConfig` class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
...
```

and added import annotation to main spring config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.gepick.*")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
...
```

If I understand well, now when open project on browser spring should redirect me to default spring security login form for authorization (`.anyRequest().authenticated()`), but in my situation not redirecting, but open web app without authorization form. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the springSecurityFilterChain in your web.xml?

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: After searching for 3 hours, thanks :)